# How to reproduce scipy.convolve with theano

Tags: python, scipy, theano, convolution

I've read the previous responses regarding the theano `conv1d` problem but I can't seem to make it work:

```
x = np.arange(50) * 1.
y = np.random.normal((x+0.1)/5, 1, 50)

def tophat(x, centre, width, amplitude):
    return tt.switch((x < centre + (width/2)) & (x >= centre - (width/2)), np.float64(amplitude) / width,  np.float64(0.))

import theano.tensor.signal.conv
def theano_convolve(x, y, filt_range, centre, width, amplitude):
    a = tt.matrix('a', dtype='float64')
    b = tt.matrix('b', dtype='float64')

    filt = tophat(b, centre, width, amplitude)

    func = tt.signal.conv.conv2d(a, filt, (1, y.shape[0]), (1, filt_range.shape[0]), border_mode='full') / filt.sum()

    return theano.function([a, b], func)(y[None, :], filt_range[None, :])

from scipy.signal import convolve

def scipy_convolve(x, y, filt_range, centre, width, amplitude):
    a = tt.vector('a')
    filt = theano.function([a], tophat(a, centre, width, amplitude))(filt_range)
    return convolve(y, filt, mode='same') / sum(filt)

convolved_theano = theano_convolve(x, y, np.linspace(-10, 10, len(x)), 0, 3, 1)

convolved_scipy = scipy_convolve(x, y, np.linspace(-10, 10, len(x)), 0, 3, 1)

plt.plot(x, y, '.', label='data')
plt.plot(r[0], label='theano')
plt.plot(convolved_scipy, label='scipy');
plt.legend();
```

[image]

This results in a zero-padded convolution with theano. I could just strip out the zeroes but I'd rather know what is going on!

How do you convolve a tophat function with some data (1-dimensional) in theano?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you see is caused by the different `mode` you use for the two convolutions.

In the `scipy.signal.convolve` you use `mode='same'` while in the `theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d` you use `mode='full'`.

Changing the `scipy.signal.convolve` to use `mode='full'` yields the exact same 
 vector. For the image I added `.1` to the theano vector to make the line visible and not overlap with the sicpy.convolve one.

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as tt
import seaborn as sns

plt = sns.plt

x = np.arange(50) * 1.
y = np.random.normal((x+0.1)/5, 1, 50)

def tophat(x, centre, width, amplitude):
    return tt.switch((x < centre + (width/2)) & (x >= centre - (width/2)), np.float64(amplitude) / width,  np.float64(0.))

import theano.tensor.signal.conv
def theano_convolve(x, y, filt_range, centre, width, amplitude):
    a = tt.matrix('a', dtype='float64')
    b = tt.matrix('b', dtype='float64')

    filt = tophat(b, centre, width, amplitude)

    func = tt.signal.conv.conv2d(a, filt, (1, y.shape[0]), (1, filt_range.shape[0]), border_mode='full') / filt.sum()

    return theano.function([a, b], func)(y[None, :], filt_range[None, :])

from scipy.signal import convolve

def scipy_convolve(x, y, filt_range, centre, width, amplitude):
    a = tt.vector('a')
    filt = theano.function([a], tophat(a, centre, width, amplitude))(filt_range)
    return convolve(y, filt, mode='full') / sum(filt)

convolved_theano = theano_convolve(x, y, np.linspace(-10, 10, len(x)), 0, 3, 1)

convolved_scipy = scipy_convolve(x, y, np.linspace(-10, 10, len(x)), 0, 3, 1)

plt.plot(x, y, '.', label='data')
plt.plot(convolved_theano[0]+0.1, label='theano')
plt.plot(convolved_scipy, label='scipy')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=True)
```

[image: scipy vs theano convolution]

Unfortunately looking at the [theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html?highlight=border_mode#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d) conv2d for theano does not support `border_mode='same'`.

Comment: probably can fix the border before sending the data to convolution.